# Installing Windows 10 bad sector on SSD

Tags: windows-10, ssd, windows-installation

I am handing an SSD with Ubuntu installed on it. Ubuntu said SSD has one bad sector. Now I want to install Windows 10. I believe that bad sector are market by the OS. But what happens if I install Windows on it? While installing Windows will not see if this sector is bad. Will it work out or could it lead to a problem?

Comment: The sector is marked by the disk as being bad so Windows will honor that. It should work.

Comment: Normally a bad sector should be replaced by reserve sector or is just not used by the controller anymore. Therefore Windows should not encounter any bad sector. However if you encounter a bad sector you should monitor the SSD if it is not near it's end of life.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the disk.

Disks (both HDDs and SSDs) are capable of self-healing to some extent. They have some amount of spare sectors that are not accessible under normal operation. When a bad sector is detected, the disk will try to copy its content to a spare sector and permanently substitute the bad sector with a spare one. This sector won't be reported to the operating system because the disk managed to keep it functional.

If your disk is reporting uncorrectable bad sectors, it means it ran out of spares. It's an indication that something's wrong with the disk and more sectors are failing than usual. When next ones will fail, the disk won't be able to replace them with spares and you'll be losing data.

Filesystems are capable of marking sectors as bad, but it doesn't protect you from data loss due to next sector failures. It's a last resort "life support" feature that lets you use the disk (if you really need to) until a replacement is available.

As always: make sure you have working, up-to-date, restorable backups of all irreplaceable data. You *will* lose some data sooner or later, if not due to this disk's failure, then due to next one's, or malware activity, or power surge, or simply by deleting an important file by mistake. Automated backups are the only reliable way to recover in these situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to install Windows on a disk with an uncorrectable error,
then format the disk when installing Windows.

Choose full format (not the fast method) and wait for however long the format takes.

This will detect and mark all *current* hard disk defects.
But there is no guarantee that new ones will not arrive in the future.